# Create a reusable sign in method for internjs

Tags: javascript, selenium, intern

There are several suites where I need to start testing after signing in. I have created a setup function that instructs the remote to sign in, but it's not very efficient.

I would like to create a helper function that signs in first before running my test and something I can easily reuse for other suites. In a python selenium framework I used decorators for this.

Would I have to create a functions and wrap everything in a registerSuite with that function?

Any guidance would be much appreciated,

Gregg

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to create a separate file in your intern directory to handle any utility functions that you are going to reuse. The following example is for functional tests as I haven't written any unit tests with Intern.

Adding something like util.js to your intern directory

`project_root/
  node_modules/
    intern/
  tests/
    functional/
    unit/
    intern.js
    util.js`

Inside the util.js file define a new AMD module

```
define([
'intern!object',
'intern/chai!assert',
'require',

], function (registerSuite, assert, require, util) {

        login_web: function() {
            return this.remote
                .get("http://loginurl.com/?user-name=user&password=pass")
        },
    }
})
```

Then inside your intern test you can call the util function with

```
login: util.login_web
```

Hope this puts your on the right track.